# Cannot pass data from Parent to Child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Do you have any idea about the strange problem below?

I am passing data from a parent to a child component that is returned from a service method returning data as `Observable<DemoModel>`. But, when child component is loading, the data is undefined and it is only filled after `ngAfterViewInit` (I also tried getting the data on this method, but the data is still undefined). So, I also tried to apply some `ngOnchanges` approach, but the problem is much more related to that the data retrieved from Parent Component is not ready while Child Component is loading (I also tried to use async, etc. instead of subscribe. How should I get data to make it ready while child component is loading?

Parent and Child Components are shown below:

**Parent Comp**

```
<child-component
    [courses]="courses|async" 
>
</child-component>



courses: any;

this.service.listCourses().subscribe((course: Course) => {
  this.courses = course;
});
```

**Child Comp**

```
private courses: any;

@Input()
set data(data: any) {
    this.courses.next(data);
}

myControl = new FormControl('');

ngAfterViewInit() {

  // >>> THIS THROWS ERROR AS this.courses is undefined
  this.myControl.setValidators([
    Validators.required,
    forbiddenNamesValidator(this.courses)
  ]);
}
```

I also tried to use some `*ngIf` in html, but as the `this.courses` parameter is used in the methods, it does not make any sense to check the data in html.

The problem may be caused by subscribe method, but I also tried to use promise (I am not sure if I used it properly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### There's a couple things wrong with your current implementation:

- In your Parent component, courses is an array (I assume) not an observable - no need to use the `async` pipe
- In your Child component you've named the input field `data`, and used a setter to call `.next` on a variable that should be an array - i.e. `.next` wont exist.

#### The below should fix your current implementation

Parent Comp

```
<child-component
    [courses]="courses" 
>
</child-component>

courses: any;

this.service.listCourses().subscribe((course: Course) => {
  this.courses = course;
});
```

Child Comp

```
@Input() courses: any;
```

#### It's important to note that `listCourses` is asynchronous

What this means is that `courses` won't necessarily be guaranteed to have a value when `ngAfterViewInit` is called and will likely then throw a similar error.

What I can suggest to solve this is the following:

```
<child-component
    *ngIf="courses?.length"
    [courses]="courses" 
>
</child-component>
```

You won't then have to wait for `ngAfterViewInit`, and instead can just wait for `ngOnInit`.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myControl.setValidators([
        Validators.required,
        forbiddenNamesValidator(this.courses)
    ]);
}
```

#### Comments

> Passing a list from parent to child, should I use an observable/promise/array etc?

That's entirely up to you, I prefer using the `async` pipe when dealing with observables, because then I don't need to worry about unsubscribing from my subscriptions.

```
<child-component
    [courses]="courses | async" 
>
</child-component>

courses = this.service.listCourses()
```

> I think there is no need to use get/set for the courses in Child Component as the list will not be changed

You don't necessarily need to even use a get/set when engaging with data that changes. Angular will update the `@Input` data for you, so you don't need worry about using a get/set unless you explicitly need that functionality.

> Should I call the `this.myControl.setValidators([]}` and the filter method in the `onInit` or `afterViewInit`

There's no need to shift setting the validator into your `afterViewInit`, you don't need to wait for your Component's View to be initialized before you set the validator.

Comment: **1.** What would you suggest in order to pass a list tfrom parent to child? Using `async` with an observable variable or `promise`, etc? As my `listCourses()` method returns `Observable` would it be better to use async?

Comment: ***2.*** I think there is no need to use get/set for the courses in Child Component as the list will not be changed (actually it loads the SelectList values. So, it may be better not to subscribe maybe, what shoudl I use in this scene for filling the list in Parent Component?

Comment: ***3.*** Should I call the `this.myControl.setValidators([]}` and the filter method ib the Child Component on `onInit` or `afterViewInit` in Child Component?

Comment: Updated, remember that if an answer solved your problem - please mark it as accepted so your question can be closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for one by one and detailed explanations.

Comment: I marked as answer, but I cannot vote up as I have not enough repo. Any vote up to my question?

Answer (score 1):

1st way: Add `ngIf` to check whether you have data or not.

```
<child-component [courses]="courses" *ngIf="courses.length > 0"> </child-component>
```

2nd Way : If you want use `async` then don't subscribe it in your component.

```
<child-component [courses]="courses$ | async" *ngIf="(courses$| async)?.length > 0"> </child-component>
```

Component:

```
courses$: Observable<any>;

this.courses$ = this.service.listCourses().pipe(shareReplay());
```

Comment: The input variable name is also wrong in the child component.

Comment: @uiTeam324 Is there anything to be corrected before I try?

Comment: @uiTeam324 As the course list is used for filling a dropdownlist, and will not be changed, would it be better not to subscribe it? If so, why use `.pipe(shareReplay()` part rather than only using `this.service.listCourses()`?

Comment: @PragDopravy, If you use `async` multiple times in the same view it will call the API endpoint multiple times. `shareReplay` will prevent that and share the data between themselves by doing it through a single call.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I cannot vote up as I have not enough repo. Any vote up to my question?